# What context-free grammar recognizes a list of numbers 1 - N in order?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I'm looking for a context-free grammar that recognizes precisely the numbers `1` - `N` in order:

`1,10,11,100` valid (numbers `1` - `4` in base-2)

`1,1,10,11,100` invalid (duplicate `1`)

`1,10,100` invalid (missing `3`)

`10,1,11,100` invalid (has all numbers but `1` and `2` are not in the correct position)

I'm not sure where to start to create the grammar.

The closest I could come up with are these rules, which I believe recognize a list of `N` natural numbers (with no constraints to order or duplicates or missings).

```
S -> B
B -> B,B | 1A | 1
A -> AA | 1 | 0
```

`A`, `B`, `S` are non-terminals

`1`, `0`, `,` are terminals

`S` is start symbol

What context-free grammar recognizes a list of numbers `1` - `N` in order?

Comment: What makes you so sure this language is context-free?

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm not sure. 

I thought "if solvable in polynomial time, then there exists a context-free grammar for it" and you can recognize a sorted list of integers in polynomial time by incrementing a counter and comparing the items in the list to the counter after each increment, so I figured there must be a context-free grammar that does the same.

Comment: @Nathaniel "Context Free Grammar Membership – Given a context-free grammar and a string, can that string be generated by that grammar?" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete

Comment: The fact that the CFG membership problem is in $\mathsf{P}$ has nothing to do with the fact that any language in $\mathsf{P}$ is context-free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language $L$ is not context-free, so there is no CFG generating it.

Indeed, suppose it is context-free, and let $n$ be the pumping length. Let $u \in L$ be a word of length $\geqslant n$ (for example $u = 1, 2, …, n$ in binary). The [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) states that $u$ can be written $u = vwxyz$ such that:

1. $|wxy| \leqslant n$;
2. $|wy| > 0$;
3. for all $k\geqslant 0$, $vw^kxy^kz\in L$.

Suppose there is a decomposition $u = vwxyz$ verifying the first two points. Without loss of generality, suppose $w\neq \varepsilon$ (the same reasonning can be done if $y\neq \varepsilon$). Then:

- if $w$ contains two symbols `,`, then $w^2$ will contain twice the same number, so $vw^2xy^2z$ contains repetitions so is not in $L$;
- if $w$ contains no symbol `,`, then $vw^2xy^2z$ will skip some numbers (we made the integer where $w$ appears bigger), so it is not in $L$;
- if $w$ is exactly `,`, then $vw^2xy^2z$ contains `,,` so it is not in $L$;
- finaly, if $w = w_1,w_2$ with $w_1$ and $w_2\in\{0,1\}^*$, then $vw^3xy^3z$ will contain $w_1,w_2w_1,w_2w_1,w_2$, so it contains twice the number $w_2w_1$, so it is not in $L$.

In all cases, the decomposition does not satisfy the third item. By contradiction, we conclude $L$ is not context-free.